# jQuery Tree Structure with Divs

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a Tree Structure exactly like this example, but with divs (not using a table):

https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart

The reason I'd like to do this is that I'd like to have more flexibility with scaling the vertical distance between different elements, so I want to avoid using a row structure.

Does anyone have a good example of how to do this?